# angularJS scope not updated for function attribute inside promise block

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, promise, angularjs-controller

```
controller('SomeController', function($scope, simpleFactory, $routeParams) {

    init();

    function init() {
        var myDataPromise = simpleFactory.getStuff($routeParams.id);

        // The method A works fine here
        $scope.A = function() {
          //return result['someAttrOfResult']
          return 90
        }

        myDataPromise.then(function(result) {
            // B is a regular object and works fine
            $scope.B = result;

            // The method A does not work here
            $scope.A = function() {
                //return result['someAttrOfResult']
                return 90
            }
        })


}
```

In my view I can do something like this:

```
<h1>{{B.someAttrOfResult}}</h1>
```

but not something like this, unless I create method A() outside the promise block:

```
<mydirective value="A()" ></mydirective>
```

Of course my endgame is to have A() return any attribute of the object, not the hardcoded value. But even hardcoding the return value does not work inside the promise. If I move it outside, setting it to $scope.B['someAttrOfResult'] does not work because the promise might not have been completed yet.

Comment: It will probably depend on which scope symbol ('=','@','&') you used for your mydirective. I believe only '&' will interpolate the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on in the simpleFactory.getStuff method so I could be wrong, but probably you are missing a $scope.$apply() call for the promise to "settle". Angular's $q promises are not immediately resolved/rejected when the asynchroneous operation completes/fails, but they're settled in the next $digest phase.

The promises that are returned from eg. the $http service do not have this problem since they have the necessary calls to the digest cycle already built in, but when you use the 'raw' $q service you need to trigger this settling of promises manually with $scope.$apply(). Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried to add $scope.$apply() but I got a "digest already in progress" error, maybe I did put in the wrong place. Where should it be?

Comment: If you get this message, then the problem is not the settlement of the promise. Actually could have figured that out since you can address $scope.B just fine... Could it be that it's the directive that is causing the problem? Here's a plunker of an approximation of your situation, but it is working (without $scope.apply() even). After 5 seconds you can click on the button and myValue will change to abcd. http://plnkr.co/edit/hPMngI73yLT4f66KrP66

Comment: Thanks much Simon! Your example works however I had to click the button twice. First time I get the same error about digest in progress. In my case I'm using a directive and have no button to click so my directive stays undefined :(

Comment: You get the error because I was stupid and left the $scope.$apply() in my plunker :). Could you show how your directive is defined?

Comment: Still it does not explain why I need to clik the button twice for the change to apply. My directive is very similar to the D3 gauge showed here: https://github.com/nickholub/angular-real-time-charts. The most significant change is in the app/scripts/directives/gauge.js file, I replace references to scope.value, with scope.A(), where A() is the function that returns the value for the gauge. And I only did that because I was unable to have something like {{myValue}} to work inside the directive.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was a typo :(, the original code for the directive had the following:

```
scope.$watch('value', function () {
      if (scope.gauge) {
        scope.gauge.redraw(scope.value);       
      }
});
```

When I replaced {{value}} with a function call, "value()", I forget to replace the watch above to read:

```
scope.$watch('value()', function () {
      if (scope.gauge) {
        scope.gauge.redraw(scope.value());       
      }
});
```

I did change the redraw call but not he scope.$watch one.